# Postgresql error when I try psql

Tags: postgresql

i am getting this error,,

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What's the problem? I'm using postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 17.04 x64

Comment: The problem is that there is no server at the location you are trying to connect to, or that server is not accepting connections due to permissions, business, initialization, and incorrect connection attempt, or...

Answer (score 1):

Is the postgres deamon running, i.e. what is the output of

```
pg_lsclusters -h
```

? If it is not running, you can use

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

to start it.

Answer (score 0):

First Start the server:

*../bin/pg_ctl start*

then connect to the database

*psql dbname*